# Appropriate numpy/scipy function to interpolate function defined on simplex (non regular grid)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, numerical-methods

I've got a function defined on a 3-dimensional simplex. That is, the set of points x, y, z, each between 0 and 1, such that x + y + z = 1.0

For example, if I consider 4 points for each x, y and z, then I'll get a a (10, 3) numpy array that looks like this (each row sums up to exactly 1):

```
points = array([[0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 0.33333333, 0.66666667],
       [0.        , 0.66666667, 0.33333333],
       [0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.        , 0.66666667],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.66666667, 0.        ],
       [0.66666667, 0.        , 0.33333333],
       [0.66666667, 0.33333333, 0.        ],
       [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

I add the convenience function that generates a simplex:

```
def generate_simplex_3dims(n_per_dim):
    xlist = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n_per_dim)
    ylist = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n_per_dim)
    zlist = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n_per_dim)
    return np.array([[x, y, z] for x in xlist for y in ylist for z in zlist
                     if np.allclose(x+y+z, 1.0)])
```

I'll also have values for those points. As an example, let's generate the values like this:

```
def approx_this_f(x, y, z):
    return 2*x - y + 5*z

values = np.empty(len(points))
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    values[i] = approx_this_f(point[0], point[1],
                         point[2])
```

My objective is to get an `interpolated_f` that I can use to evaluate like  `interpolated_f([0.3, 0.5, 0.2])` or `interpolated_f(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)` for arbitrary points within the simplex.

I looked through the documentation, but don't understand what is the appropriate interpolator here, given that my grid points are defined on a simplex and that I want to get an interpolated function back.

I tried `scipy.interpolate.griddata` and it only worked with `method='nearest'` and this one returns an array of values, but I need an interpolated function. I saw other functions on `scipy`that return an interpolated function, but seem to only work with regular grids.

Thanks!

---- Example with `griddata` in case it helps ------

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
xi = generate_simplex_3dims(n_per_dim=20) #Generates lots of points
interpolated_grid = griddata(points, values, xi,
         method='linear') #this fails
interpolated_grid = griddata(points, values, xi,
         method='nearest') #this works, but returns a grid, not a function
```

The `method=linear` threw and error, but, more im

Comment: Is regularGridInterpolator useful here ?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf I think I can't use it. The domain of the function is a simplex which, I think, can't be written as a regular grid (but it would be great if it can be!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer by @user6655984 I figured out how to do it (thanks!)

I gave it a bit more thought and I'm pretty sure that (thought I'd be happy to be corrected):

1. The simplex domain means it can't have a regular grid (some parts of the space won't have a value)
2. That I need to delete one dimension for the interpolation to work. Since in a 3D simplex the elements need to add up to one, I'll have [0.4, 0.3, 0.3], but I can't have [0.4, 0.3, 0.5], so in fact the function will only have values on a 2D subspace of 3D!

Let's have the same setup as in the question

```
def approx_this_f(x, y, z):
    return 2*x - y + 5*z

#Uses the function defined in the question
simplex_points = generate_simplex_3dims(10)
values = np.empty(len(simplex_points))
for i, lambda_0 in enumerate(simplex_points):
    values[i] = approx_this_f(lambda_0[0], lambda_0[1],
                         lambda_0[2])
```

Because of comment number 2, the following doesn't work:

```
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator

interpolated = LinearNDInterpolator(simplex_points, values)
```

and throws this error

```
QhullError: qhull precision warning: 
The initial hull is narrow (cosine of min. angle is 0.9999999999999999).
Is the input lower dimensional (e.g., on a plane in 3-d)?  Qhull may
produce a wide facet.
```

So I need to pass the points with one less dimension (i.e., only columns 1 and 2, not the third one):

```
interpolated = LinearNDInterpolator(simplex_points[:, 0:2], values)
```

Now we can evaluate it on other points

```
#Silly code to make the original function take a matrix
def approx_this_f_vec(array):
    res = np.empty(len(array))
    for row in range(len(array)):
         res[row] = approx_this_f(*array[row])
     return res

points_test = src.generate_simplex_3dims(50) #1275 new points
interpolated_vals = interpolated_f(points_test[:, 0:2])
real_values = approx_this_f_vec(points_test)

print((interpolated_vals - real_values).max())
```

gives `1.77e-15` which means the interpolation did pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

You want a method that (a) accepts unstructured N-dimensional data points (with N > 2), and (b) returns a callable. Reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) I see two options

- [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator) -   piecewise linear interpolation only.
- [Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf) - uses radial basis functions; smooth but will not respect monotonicity or max/min values of your data  like a piecewise linear interpolator would.

Try both, and decide what's better for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! I upvoted your answer, but I found out that, because the domain is the simplex, I should delete one dimension. I'll write an answer explaining that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using simpllex_grid and linear interpolation:

```
import dit
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dim = 3 #dimensions
res= 10  #resolution
grid = list(dit.simplex_grid(dim, res, using=np.array))
grid = list(map(list, zip(*grid)))  #transpose
x = grid[0]
y = grid[1]
z = np.hypot(x, y) #Hypothenuse function (as a function of only 2 variables of the simplex)
X = np.linspace(min(x), max(x)) #Creates a mesh with may points (around 50)
Y = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)  # 2D grid for interpolation
interp = LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
Z = interp(X, Y) #This is the function! :D (returns nah if outside of sample)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, shading='auto')
plt.plot(x, y, ".",color="black", label="input point")
plt.legend()
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

The image output can be found here:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K01u.png